# prove that sequence $\frac{n^2+1}{n+4}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can somebody help me prove this sequence?

I've tried using Comparison Theorem and ended up with

$a_n = \frac{n^2+1}{n+4} < \frac{n^2}n = n > N = M$.

So I choose $N = M$.

But I don't think this is correct.

Comment: If you have inequality signs in both directions, then you don't know how to compare the far left to the far right...   The statement $x < y$ and the statement $y>z$ do not together imply anything about the relationship between $x$ and $z$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\frac{n^2+1}{n+4} \geq \frac{n^2+1}{n+n} > \frac{n^2}{2n}=\frac{n}{2}.$$
The first inequality holds for $n \geq 4$. Also we know the behavior of $\left\{\frac{n}{2}\right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n^2+1}{n+4}}n=1$$and therefore, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n+4}=\infty$ too.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \ge 4$:

$n^2+1>n^2-16=(n-4)(n+4)$;

Then

$\dfrac{n^2+1}{n+4} \gt  \dfrac{(n+4)(n-4)}{n+4}=n-4$;

$b_n=n-4$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

To show divergence, use an underestimate.

One is this:

$$\frac{n^2+1}{n+4}\ge\frac{n^2-16}{n+4}\ge\frac{n-4}{1}=n-4,$$ which clearly goes to infinity as $n\to\infty.$ Then it follows that the original sequence, which is not less than this, must also diverge at infinity.